# Подскажите как заменить Collections в классе

Tags: java

Есть класс, в котором сортировка производится в коллекции... Как заменить коллекцию на что-то другое (более "упрощенное"), при этом сохранив сортировку и т.д.?

```java
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class AirlineSorter {
    /*
     * Method sorting planes in airline fleet by it's flight range:
     * put's the plane with lowest flight range parameter to the
     * begging of airline planes list, plane with highest flight
     * range to the end of airline planes list.
     *
     * @param airline airline
     */
    public void sortPlanesByFlightRange(Airline airline) {
        Comparator<Plane> comparator = new Comparator<Plane>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Plane o1, Plane o2) {
                if (o1.getFlightRange() - o2.getFlightRange() > 1) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (o1.getFlightRange() - o2.getFlightRange() < 1) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(airline.getFleet().getPlanes(), comparator);
    }
}
```

Comment: лучше не делать его короче... стримы и т.д не для этого задания(к сожалению)((

Comment: Нужно как то избавиться от коллекции на что то другое(я просто не знаю на что)... сохранив при этом функциональность кода

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под коллекцией? `Collections`? это всего лишь название util класса в котором хранится статическая функция sort, зачем от него избавляться, если вам нужна сортировка?

Comment: "заменить коллекцию на что-то другое" звучит больше как загадка, а не как задача. Это задача на знание алгоритмов сортировки?

Comment: У меня в задании нельзя использовать коллекции... я вроде написал код... но без Collections это не получается(( Если это не коллекция... то в принципе вопроса тогда и нет))) Просто я не очень шарю... и вопрос может звучать глупо

Comment: Надо уточнить у того, кто задавал задачу. Дело в том, что [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) принимает на вход `List` который расширяет интерфейс `Collection`. Так что без коллекций не получится. Фактически, коллекция - это то, что возвращает строка `airline.getFleet().getPlanes()`. Наверное всё таки имеется в виду реализация своего алгоритма, а не использование уже готового из утилитарного класса `Collections`

Comment: А как бы выглядел "собственный" алгоритм? Я использую в других местах динамические массивы... как написать свой алгоритм по сортировке?

Comment: Сортируйте в ручную используя свой Comparator.

Comment: По факту вы используете только sort

Comment: Что-то с `>1` и `<1` фигня...

Answer (score 1):

Вы снова заходите не с той стороны. Для сортировки есть всего 3 пути:

1. писать свой класс, выполняющий сортировку (треш редкий);
2. возложить эту почетную обязанность на базу данных, если, конечно , она есть (в чем я в данном случае сомневаюсь);
3. использовать механизмы сортировки Java.

Остановимся на последнем пункте.

Вы должны понимать, что с одной стороны есть данные, которые сортируются (в данном случае это класс Plane). Разумеется, экземпляров этих классов несколько (иначе нечего будет сортировать), и также разумеется, что этих самых несколько экземпляров надо где-то хранить (фактически объявить переменную, на это способную). И тут всего 2 варианта - коллекции (и их очень много на любую задачу и это не только родные джавовские, но и множество сторонних реализаций от гугла, апача и т.д, что дает максимальную гибкость) и массивы.

Теперь вернемся к модели. Ваша модель содержит множество полей и, разумеется, для сортировки нужно описать логику этой самой сортировки. Для описания этой логики используется 2 интерфейса Comparable и Comparator. Оба работают с помощью дженериков. В случае с Comparable его должна имплементировать сама модель (Plane, соответвенно при имплементации мы напишем дженерик `implements Comparable  <Plane>`, чтобы в аргументах метода, который предстоит переопределит работать с объектом  `Plane`, а не `Object`). При этом от вас потребуется переопределние метода `compare`, как уже сказано, принимающий экземпляр класса Plane, где вы и опишите логику сравнения принимаемого объекта со своим текущим объектом. Это работает до тех пор, пока у вас единственный критерий сравнения.

Если же вам в разных местах бизнесс-логики необходимо сортировать по разным критериям, то `Comparable` вам не подойдет (ведь метод `compare` дважды в одном классе не переопределишь), и тогда вам нужен Comparator. Здесь подход немного другой. Для каждого отдельного критерия сортировки мы создаем отдельный класс, именно этот класс, а не сама модель, теперь будет имплементировать `Comparator` (он тоже с дженериком, поэтому пишем аналогично предыдущему `implements Comparator <Plane>`). И опять нужно переопределить единственный метод `compareTо`, но он уже принимает 2 аргумента (2 экземпляра класса `Plane`, ведь с текущим, т.е. `this` уже не сравнишь, это же отдельный от модели класс). Логика переопределения аналогичная.

Теперь другая сторона медали - место в коде откуда непосредствено осуществляется вызов сортировки. В этом случае у вас уже есть либо коллекция Plane (поддающаяся сортировке, потому как, к примеру, HashSet отсортировать нельзя), либо массив Plane, который нужно отсортировать. В первом случае (не рассматривая тяжелые случаи) это имплементации интерфейса List. И снова у вас два пути:

1. у листа есть метод `list.sort(comparator)`, именно в аргументы этого метода и передается экземпляр класса, а котором мы имплементировали компаратор, поскольку таких классов мы можем написать много, то и сортировать можем по разным критериям;
2. статический метод утилитного класса `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`, который перегружен и может быть вызван с одним аргументом `Collections.sort(list)`, первый случай аналогичен вызову у листа - передаем наш лист и экземпляр класса, имплементирующего компаратор, второй случай нужен в том случае, если вы использовали не Comparator, а Comparable, следовательно, "научили" непосредственно модель выполнять сортировку.

   Что касается массива, тут все идентично Collections, но вместо последнего мы используем утилитный класс `Arrays`, его методы полностью сходны с методами Collections, только теперь вместо листа массив -  `Arrays.sort(array, comparator)` и `Arrays.sort(array)`. Вот и все...

И последнее... Когда имплементируете `Comparator` или `Comparable`, то используйте в модели не примитивы, а ссылочные типы, ведь для них уже переопределены все нужные вам методы. Тогда не нужно писать условные операторы и возвращать -1,1,0, как вы делали, а достаточно сделать так:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class FlightRangeSorter implements Comparator<Plane>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Plane o1, Plane o2) {
        return o1.getFlightRange().compareTo(o2.getFlightRange());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну форматирование же не просто так придумали... Кажется, последний `Arrays.sort(comparator)` должен быть `Arrays.sort(array)`?

Comment: С рекомендацией использовать ссылочные обёртки в модели не согласен.

Comment: @ Qwertiy Arrays.sort(comparator) - это опечатка, там, разумеется Arrays.sort(array). А с сылочными обертками хотелось бы аргументированее

Comment: Ну мне кажется, что примитивы в большинстве случаев удобнее в использовании. Вообще, чисто моё мнение, особо обосновать я его не могу, просто высказал. Кстати, есть же метод `Integer.compare`.

Comment: @ Qwertiy дело не в методе. можно совсем без него return int1-int2; все дело как раз в том, что большая часть вашей бизнесс-логики будет вынуждена использовать обертки, а не примитивы (начиная с орм и заканчивая сериализаторами контроллеров в стандартном приложении). практически все, что вы используете из коробки (коллекции, лямбды, которые базируются на функциональных интерфесах, в целом все дженерики и т.д.) работают именно с ссылочным типом, потому как все упирается в итоге в то, что примитивы не являются наследниками Object. а постоянная упаковка-распаковка тоже не бесплатная

Comment: @Дмитрий пишет что невозможно вызвать "Невозможно вызвать compareTo (int) для примитива типа int"... для вот этой строчки "return o1.getFlightRange().compareTo(o2.getFlightRange());"

Comment: @ Qwertiy хотя, если совсем честно, то лично в моей практике были случаи, когда действительно использование именно примитивов давали значительный прирост производительности, но во-первых, эти случаи слишком специфичны, во-вторых, приходилось очень постараться, чтобы получить от их использования преимущества. например, приходилось использовать альтернативные коллекции (либо гугла, либо апача), которые умеют работать с примитивами. так что да, пожалуй соглашусь, что в некоторых случаях это вполне оправдано.

Comment: @Никита Кузьмищев вы невнимательно читаете. для примитивов (int) такого метода нет, вам нужно поменять в классе примитив на ссылочный тип int на Integer, либо воспользоваться способами в комментариях. просто сейчас ваш код в компараторе избыточный. для целочисленных значений он в любом случае однострочный (проверки на null тут не рассмтариваются)

Comment: @Дмитрий, спасибо, понял. А по поводу `return int1-int2;` - есть косяк с переполнением. `int int1 = 0, int2 = -2147483648` ;)

Comment: @Дмитрий А в каком классе я должен заменить примитив на ссылочный тип? в этом же... или другом? И как это должно выглядеть? типа того Integer[] array = new Integer[20]; мне переделать целый исходный массив для того что бы стала доступна сортировка через compare?

Comment: @ Qwertiy да, теоретически перполнение действительно возможно и в целом, разумеется, корректнее использовать Integer.compare. мало того, это специально написанный метод и читается он намного легче, чем метод, написанный руками. ожидаемое инженерное решение всегда лучше. тут я полностью согласен. но только  практически, если вам встречаются столь малые или столь большие значения, то в инт их заталкивать точно не стоит, иначе получите проблемы с переполнением в каком-то другом месте.

Comment: @Никита Кузьмищев в вашем классе Plane  есть переменная flightRange и она сейчас int, измените ее на Integer и все скомпилируется. Для сортировки передаете исходный массив, в котором должны лежать экземпляры класса Plane  , т.е.ваш массив объявлен так Plane  [] array = new Plane  [20], вызов сортировки таков Arrays.sort(array , new FlightRangeSorter ()); после этого массив array будет отсортирован в порядке, предусмотренном классом FlightRangeSorter

Comment: @Дмитрий, ну иногда такие значения могут использоваться в качестве специальных, типа признаков ошибок или особых системных id. // Вроде с пробелом после собаки уведомления не приходят.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, это возможно, но это уже частные случаи. на частных случаях общие правила работают не всегда. это ближе к примеру, о котором я писал выше, где пришлось использовать альтернативную коллекцию, работающую с примитивами. хотя в болишенстве случаев я бы взял какой-то ArrayList и был был бы счастлив)))

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите за основу quickSort

```
public void quickSort(Plane arr[], int begin, int end) {
    if (begin < end) {
        int partitionIndex = partition(arr, begin, end);
 
        quickSort(arr, begin, partitionIndex-1);
        quickSort(arr, partitionIndex+1, end);
    }
}


private int partition(Plane arr[], int begin, int end) {
Plane pivot = arr[end];
int i = (begin-1);

for (int j = begin; j < end; j++) {
    if (comparator.compare(arr[j], pivot)<=0) {
        i++;

        Plane swapTemp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = swapTemp;
    }
}

Plane swapTemp = arr[i+1];
arr[i+1] = arr[end];
arr[end] = swapTemp;

return i+1;
}
```

И реализуйте sort и замените List.

Comment: if (comparator.compare(arr[j], pivot)<=0) ругается на comparator... что я делаю не так? И где мне нужно заменить List ? И что значит "реализовать sort"?

Comment: Его тут нет. Объявите comparator выше по уровню шоб было видно

Comment: таак... это ведь не java.util... в этом классе он объявлен...где то еще надо объявить?Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method compare(Object, Object) from the type Comparato вот такая ошибка если я его объявляю и он становится с большой буквы